# Realtime JSON string transfer from android/ios app to a Windows software

Tags: python, json, sockets, transfer, instant

I want to create an android/ios app that would send a normal string (or a json) to a software in Windows which i will also make.  Example, in my mobile app when i press a button, the text on my Windows software will change to whatever text that was sent by my the mobile app in realtime, not after 1 minute or so.

- I will use python for that Windows software.
- I will also have an azure/aws cloud virtual machine instance that will serve as my "bridge" server for this string communication transfer between mobile app and the windows software.

My questions are:

- What is the best way to code this?
- What's the best practice of doing this kind of real time transfers?

NOTE: I have minimal experience with socket programming and I'm curious if that's the "industry standard" of doing this kind of tasks or if there's an easier way of doing it.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

your question covers a lot of subjects, but I'll try to give you some basic information.
basic best practices

1. Don't use raw sockets, the industry standard is mostly using an HTTP server (Django or Flask) with RESTful API using JSON as your serialization protocol. I also recommend that you'll make your server [stateless](https://medium.com/@rachna3singhal/stateless-over-stateful-applications-73cbe025f07).
2. Investigate similar use cases and **especially webhooks**. the simplest way you execute your plan is giving each end of your connection a unique id, and then, for example, `change something in phone app with` -> `create API request to your server to change something in a windows application with the id 123` -> `the server will look in its database for the address of the device with id 123` -> `the server will send an HTTP request to the windows software`. this model has many disadvantages like forcing register in the server phone apps to related windows software, what do you do if the address of the software changes (routers have dynamic IP).
3. Now, for the windows application, you may want to compile python to an executable file and create a standard installer for your program (guides are attached). I also recommend that you'll check Kivy which is a GUI framework that can be compiled to windows easily.

As mentioned, this topic is huge and if you want to create a real industry-standard application, you'll have to consider many more things like using HTTPS and other security issues, the ability to scale out your application and handle huge amounts of requests, have a CICD pipeline, testing and testing infrastructure, and many more.

some related links and guides, good luck!

- [Django web server framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/)
- [Flask best practise stack](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)
- [unit testing with pytest](https://www.guru99.com/pytest-tutorial.html)
- [testing automation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BHverY7IwU)
- [compile python with pyinstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- [create installer file for your executable](https://help.bittitan.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008269228-Create-a-Windows-Installer-Package-MSI-to-deploy-the-Device-Management-Agent)
- [Kivy](https://likegeeks.com/kivy-tutorial/)

Comment: My question about this part "-> the server will send an HTTP request to the windows software", the windows software is behind a firewall just like a normal end user.  How could we send an http request to the windows software if its behind a firewall?